# Per-item commerce shipping rules working but charging for same item twice

Tags: rules, commerce

I've read similar looking posts, but nothing addresses my particular problem.

I have 2 shipping rates and rules setup and no longer confusing each other (thanks to rfay's excellent vimeo tutorials and the discussion here: https://drupal.org/node/1415638)

One is for domestic and I'm trying to add a 50 cent per item shipping charge to a $3 base.

The other is international and I want it to add a $3 per item shipping charge to an $11 base.

I have things basically setup like rfay documents in https://drupal.org/node/1415638

And it's sort of working. The problem is it appears to be double-counting one of the items - I'm probably saying this wrong.

e.g., 4 domestic items should be base ($3) + 3*50 cents = $4.50, but it is currently computing $5.00

My international rule is behaving in the same way. How do I avoid this double-dipping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I figured it out. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I added an action to my rule, but not as part of the Loop - just beneath it (not indented). This new action is "Subtract an amount from the unit price." For data selector I entered commerce_line_item. For amount, I entered the amount of one additional item (50 for the 50 cents in my domestic shipping example).

So now my rule basically takes the base rate of $3, adds 50 cents for each item including the base item, so then the subtraction action removes that extra 50 cents. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hold on - that fix I just posted is not working right! When you get to final checkout, you have a correct shipping charge ($4.50 in my example) but it's above and part of the subtotal and the wrong amount ($5) shipping appears after the subtotal, so we're now charging $9.50 for shipping! I'll keep working on this and update when I find a real solution. I really did not want to spend 3 days on shipping! Argghhh!

Comment: In the end, I "fixed" this by just adjusting my base rates so the per item charges come out the way I want. In other words, for domestic, I made the base flat rate $2.50 and the per item calculation $ .50. So one item is $3, two are $3.50 etc. For international, I made my base flat rate $8 with the per item calc of $3 so those rates are computing how I want them. Kind of embarrassed this didn't occur to me at the start - doh!